# Is it possible to buy tickets for an international train in a third country in Europe?

Tags: trains, europe, tickets

I need to buy a ticket for an international train and, apparently, there are no websites selling it.

I once remember a friend telling me that the trains uses a system, sort of, similar to the airplanes. There is a general backend computer system that allows to find schedules everywhere and also sell tickets (eg.: you can buy  a ticket at any touristic agency). 
He also mentioned it would be possible (at least technicaly) for a train company to sell someone elses tickets on another country.

So, to wrap this, is it possible to buy a train ticket for an international train (that goes from A to B) in a third country (C)?

Edit: I tried to make the question generic, but, answering the comments, the countries A and B are Poland and Czech Republic. The country I would like to buy the ticket in (i.e. C) would be either Belgium, Netherlands, Spain or Portugal.

Note that my question is not if I can buy them online. I already asked that. My question is if I can buy them through either a travel agent or a train company (International) ticket shop.

Comment: For some countries you can (e.g. you can buy tickets for travel from France to UK online from anywhere in the world), for others it's not so easy (e.g. from Pakistan to Iran). It would help if you indicated what countries you are talking about.

Comment: Depends entirely on what the countries are - we'll really need you to specify those if we're to stand any chance of helping

Comment: In what country do you want to buy this ticket going from Poland to Czech Republic?

Comment: @Peter Raeves, Belgium, Netherlands, Spain, Portugal are all options.

Comment: @nsn Since I can't find any clear evidence online, I'll ask whether you can buy a ticket from Warsaw to Prague at Belgian stations and I'll try the ticket vending machine for Belgium.

Comment: why would you get the ticket from a ticket shop or a travel agent if you can get the ticket online? and what about online ticket shops/travel agents?

Comment: You can buy a ticket from Warsaw to Prague from the Czech Railways online here: www.cd.cz. You most certainly can't from Belgian ticket machines.

Answer (score 10):

I have tried this myself multiple times from my own country (Belgium) for different European countries (neighboring countries but also Italy, Austria, Czech Republic, Portugal, Switzerland ...)

In short, the only way to find out is trying. Some hints that might give you the best mileage:

- Forget vending machines. You won't get it there.
- Aim for main stations in major towns. It is possible that this shouldn't matter in theory, but in reality the person behind the counter will have a lot more experience with "weird" requests in a main station. Ideally you should go to a station where the have a separate counter for international travel.
- Focus on the main connections, especially the ones requiring reservations. Often you can buy those, even if it is impossible to buy tickets for regional trains. Buying the regional trains locally is usually not a big issue (unless you have a short connection time).
- Find an itinerary beforehand (I prefer the site of the DB), print it and show it. The train number can be a pointer and at least it shows the person behind the counter that she/he is looking for something that exists and not going on a wild goose chase.
- Try it during busy office hours. The more people hanging around, the higher the chance that one of them is an experienced colleague that tried it before and knows how to get it out of the computer. Or that knows it is impossible.
- Bring your thickest skin possible. You might be occupying the counter for a while. People queuing behind you might be getting nervous.
- Stay friendly and be prepared to take "Computer says 'no'" as an answer.

In the old days (say 15 years ago) you could buy more or less tickets between any arbitrary two stations. Now with privatizations and strict EU regulations on competition, the number of rail operators has exploded and the situation changes rapidly. What was possible last month, might not be possible today and the other way around. The people behind the counter often have to try themselves.

Comment: I tried a similar approach, but I chose a smaller station with a manned desk (selling international tickets, of course) to buy a Spanish RENFE train reservation (to be used with a rail pass) in Slovakia. The lady took out a big binder with instructions, it took her about 30 minutes, but in the end it worked. I had to provide exact dates and train numbers as she wasn't able to search for connections in Spain.

Answer (score 5):

To summarize and nuance the earlier answers, I know from experience that it's possible to buy tickets in or between third countries at train stations in Europe but it's often a frustrating experience. Some trains might not be available or it might be possible to get a ticket but not to book a seat. Sometimes it even depends on who you happen to ask, some railway employees seem more adept than others at finding and booking complex tickets abroad.

Also note than in some countries, booking an international ticket might require you to go to a special service desk and to pay an additional booking fee or at least to find a manned ticket office. For example in the Netherlands, many stations don't have a ticket office anymore, medium ones do but won't sell tickets outside of the Benelux and Germany and there are only a handful of [NS International desks](https://www.nsinternational.nl/nl/tickets-services/openingstijden-ticket-en-service-winkels) (the new brand for NS Hispeed) in places like Rotterdam and Amsterdam.

Whether a ticket that's not available on the web is more or less likely to be bookable at the station I don't know. I think they do use several different systems and if you find the right person, you might still have a chance to buy a ticket. The annoying thing is that a clerk who doesn't know the system very well will often be adamant that a train does not exist or is not bookable even if there was in fact a solution.

Finally, travel agents might be able to help as well (or not).

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, although in some cases it might be bit complicated. I checked the website of the Dutch railways where I noticed the following announcement:

> Online, NS International sells a wide range of both trips departing from the Netherlands to other countries (one-way and return) and coming from abroad to the Netherlands (one-way and return), as well as a limited number of routes from abroad to another foreign country (one-way and return). Other trips can be booked by telephone via Service Center (0900-9296,) and at desks at Tickets & Service offices at all medium to large train stations.

So at least in the Netherlands you should be able to buy your traintickets at the international desks at certain stations. I expect this to be similar in other countires as well.

Comment: I expected the same (Belgium here), but apparently this is different in Germany, Denmark, Sweden and Norway according to Tor-Einar Jarnbjo if you look at the comments at my answer.

Comment: I doubt @tor-einars jarnbjo's answer a bit though. I am pretty sure that at the main stations in germany there are manned desks, but I have no experience in buying those tickets in germany. I do buy inner belgium tickets in holland though.

Comment: I don't read the quoted text in the same way. “a limited number of routes from abroad to another foreign country” suggests it's generally not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to buy tickets for origins not in Switzerland and destinations in Turkey, Bulgaria, Croatia, and others over the years from the SBB (Swiss Railways) ticket office in the station.  Not necessarily from their web site, but in-person.

I also noticed that some of the automated ticket machines in Switzerland, perhaps with a newer software release, have international destinations in their destination list but they don't work (yet).  Budapest Ferihegy, Milano C, etc.

Comment: Milano Centrale doesn't work? It's served by SBB trains, and shoud definitely be available

Comment: SBB ticket machines only sell tickets for domestic journey. And SBB doesn't serve Milano Centrale anyway. The EC trains are SBB only north of Chiasso/Domodossola. South of those places they are Trenitalia trains...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

**Inside of Europe**

Local European train stations offer you the possibility to buy international tickets from and to where ever you want in Europe through either their website or their local ticket shops.

**Outside of Europe**

I'm not sure if they do, but if they don't, you could always ask them to go the European international railway website and ask them to buy the ticket online for you.

[Website to buy international European tickets](http://www.raileurope.com/index.html)

Comment: Could the downvoter explain why he downvoted?

Comment: Sorry, but this is incorrect. Many train station in Europe don't have manned ticket desks anymore and ticket vending machines are mostly very limited when it comes to selling international tickets. Even *if* there is a manned ticket desk at a station, they are not able to sell arbitrary tickets for foreign trains.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo They don't have manned ticket desks anymore? Almost every trainstation I went to had both manned desks and machines. Where do you live?

Comment: I live in Germany, but the situation is similar in Denmark, Sweden and Norway as well.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo that is incorrect, there remain quite some manned ticket desks, even in Germany and Sweden

Comment: @andra: Did I write something else? If I managed to find the correct numbers, only 420 (less than 8%) of the 5454 railway stations in Germany have manned ticket desks. According to the SJ web page (Swedish Railways), they only operate five manned ticket sale points in Stockholm C, Arlanda (Stockholm Airport), Gothenburg C, Malmö C and Sundsvall C.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Could you provide a source to these numbers?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo yes you did say something else. You down voted and said that the answer is incorrect. The OP asked for whether it was possible and it is possible. You could have added the nuance that it might be the case in only 8% of the stations. Note that in the Netherlands and Belgium the situation might be the same, hence the note: "medium to large train stations."

Comment: @andra: But the problem is not only that there must be a manned ticket desk, but that even the manned ticket desk is not able to sell tickets for arbitrary foreign trains (yes, I already wrote that). You can usually only buy tickets according the SCIS tariffe, but these are not available for all routes, not always valid in all trains and not accepted by all train operators.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo They are available in Belgium and the Netherlands. So I think this discussion is pointless unless OP tells us where he wants to buy the tickets. And maybe even towards what city he would like to go instead of just a country.

Comment: @PeterRaeves: 420 German ticket offices: http://www.db-vertrieb.com/db_vertrieb/view/leistungen/vertriebskanaele/reisezentren.shtml - 5454 German railway stations: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DB_Station&Service - 5 Swedish ticket offices: http://www.sj.se/sj/jsp/polopoly.jsp?d=5684&a=175680&l=sv - or you could have used Google and found these numbers within a few minutes.

Comment: @PeterRaeves What "they" are available in Belgium and the Netherlands?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Tickets from Poland to Czech Republic or international European tickets in general. I'll go to the train station tomorrow and verify myself, since one of OP's target countries is Belgium anyway.

Comment: @PeterRaeves: International tickets are for sure available for some routes and some trains, but not in general. For example, two weeks ago, I travelled on at train operated by Westbahn from Vienna to Salzburg. Tickets for these trains are only available online or from the train conductor and not even sold in Austrian railway stations. In Germany, I could have bought a SCIC ticket from Vienna to Salzburg, but SCIC tickets are usually not accepted by private train operators (at least not in Germany and Austria) and would not have been valid in the train I travelled with.

Comment: @PeterRaeves It might just be a case of nuances. If you would remove or change “from and to where ever you want in Europe”, it would seem to be more accurate, provide valuable information and should satisfy Tor-Einar Jarnbjo.

Comment: @Relaxed: Exactly. I have two problems with the answer, the first is "European train stations offer you the possibility ...". Yes, some stations do, but at least in the countries I regularly stay, this apply only to the larger stations and not in general. The second issue is "from and to where ever you want in Europe", which is also wrong. There are multiple train operators at least in most West European countries, and it depends both on the route, the train operator and in some cases even the train category, if and where a ticket can be bought in a different country.

Comment: "Local European train stations offer you the possibility to buy international tickets from and to where ever you want in Europe" that's just not true. Source: been to quite a few train stations which were either not manned with very limited vending machines, or did not offer the option to book tickets to at least several places in Europe

Comment: Another answer says: "in the Netherlands you should be able to buy your traintickets at the international desks at certain stations", which sounds much closer to reality